# How to retain last seen UITableViewCell when app launches like Twitter app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, twitter, uiscrollview

Am creating an application for stock market related things. Here, I have a feed screen to display list of stock details in UITableView.

Now user see the feeds and quit the application and removed it from memory. Once again user launch the application, Now app need to show whatever user saw previously at first. And load the API in background if new data are available, App have to show a Button to load new data.

Please guide me to achieve this.

Note: Twitter has this feature.

Comment: 1: https://github.com/IvanVorobei/TwitterLaunchAnimation

2: https://github.com/okmr-d/App-Launching-like-Twitter

Comment: Use Core Data to cache the existing records and use it before fetching new records.

Comment: You can simply store your data in JSON file or Core data or SQLite and load it when app launch when your api call finishes load fresh data and also replace / store that data in JSON file or Core data or SQLite for future